# Could anyone explain: (1) What are the advantages of practicing Guru Yoga? (2) Why (or What are the reasons) practicing Guru Yoga has such advantages?

Tags: vajrayana, yoga, gurus

The question is just the title. Moreover, AFAIK, currently there are 2 editions of the 14th Dalai Lama Guru Yoga.
(1)  "[The Source of All Attainments: The Yoga of the Inseparability of the Guru and Avalokiteshvara](https://fpmt.org/wp-content/uploads/teachers/zopa/advice/chenrezig-mantra-and-practice/inseparability_guru_avalokiteshvara_a5.pdf)".
(2)  "[A Stairway to Potala: Guru Yoga of Avalokiteshvara](http://media.dalailama.com/English/texts/Short-Avalokiteshvara-Sadhana-by-HHDL-ENG.pdf)".

Comment: This is a question seriously asked. Why is this get downvoted?

Comment: Hi, I downvoted this question after awhile because there did not appear to me a satisfactory answer and guru yoga or vajrayana is a very fraught subject. There are very good practitioners on this site who I have confidence could give a good answer, but the fact that they have refrained from doing so tells me something.

Comment: I don’t practice vajrayana and am of the opinion that it should only be practiced by those with tremendous wisdom and oceans of merit. That’s not me and the silence of those who have such merit and wisdom speaks loudly that this question - while earnest and seriously asked - should be downvoted at this time and in this context. Hope that helps to explain.

Comment: @YesheTenley These 2 editions of the 14th Dalai Lama Guru Yoga were/are firstly publicly taught by Gelug Dharma teachers (i.e., Geshes, Rinpoches,... ) in Dharma centers in Taiwan to students to practice, ***even to students who have never practiced Vajrayana***, when the week of the 14th Dalai Lama's birth day was coming. The Chinese edition of the 14th Dalai Lama Guru Yoga instructions, are freely available from (the publications of) the representative office of the 14th Dalai Lama and Tibet in Taiwan, and also freely available from Gelug Dharma teachers in Taiwan.

Answer (score 1):

If practiced properly from a proper teacher, it is:

The fastest way to attain enlightenment.

Some of the reasons are:

1. The guru is the Buddha
2. if the guru is the Buddha we have direct access to Buddha teaching

this because: a method was developed by the Buddha, it was transmitted Orally for the first 500 years, after that, books where introduced with the Buddhas teachings to supplement the oral teachings. This teachings are still being teach verbally and in other ways as well. Qualified teachers (Gurus) have complete understanding from where the teachings came (lineage) and there is still unbroken lineages around.

IF we choose to practice Guru yoga. It is recommended that we do our homework and find a proper teacher(s) that we can trust and we feel connected. Also absolutely proper to ask question about lineage and from who they learn. Guru Yoga and Vajrayana wont work if is from a not proper teacher and is said to be dangerous if practice wrongly.

I hope this answer the question! also sorry if there is any typo.

Comment: I upvoted this. IMO, this pretty much answers the OP. From a Vajrayāna perspective, the guru is a Perfectly Enlightened Buddha. The Saṃgha is his body, the Buddha is his mind, and the Dharma is his speech. Learning directly from a Buddha is better than learning from a non-Buddha. From a non-Vajrayāna perspective, none of this necessarily applies. The refuge is not in the guru in non-Tantric Mahāyāna, and the guru is not the three jewels in non-Tantric Mahāyāna.